# Can I make a promise that will only resolve when multiple variables are set?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to set up a promise only to resolve when both a and b condition have been met. I wrote the following to try to demonstrate what I aiming for:

```
var coreData = {}

var firstMethod = function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
//First number I want to resolve
        let firstRandomNum = Math.random();
        setTimeout(function() {
          //console.log('First Number; ' + firstRandomNum);
          coreData.firstRandomNumber = firstRandomNum;
          resolve(coreData);
        }, 2*firstRandomNum);

//Second number I want to resolve
        let secondRandomNum = Math.random();
        setTimeout(function() {
          //console.log('Second Number; ' + secondRandomNum);
          coreData.secondRandomNumber = secondRandomNum;
          resolve(coreData);
        }, 2*secondRandomNum);

    });
    return promise;
 };

 //Here is where I'd like both *both* numbers to resolve to
 var secondMethod = function(someStuff) {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          console.log('All complete');
          console.log(coreData);
    });
    return promise;
 };

 firstMethod()
    .then(secondMethod);
```

Now I can see why it's not doing what I want: as soon as either firstRandomNumber or secondRandomNumber resolve, they trigger the secondMethod, this is what I was expecting.

How can I set things up such that secondMethod will only trigger once firstRandomNumber *and* secondRandomNumber resolve? I feel like it may have something to do with [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), but I could not get this to work.

Follow-up question: Some unexpected behaviour in the above code is that every now and then both firstRandomNumber and secondRandomNumber *will* resolve. This doesn't seem to make sense to me: how could this ever happen, short of both numbers being exactly the same?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `how could this ever happen`,  if the second random number is less than the first maybe.. :)

Comment: You can only use the `resolve` callback once.

Comment: You could use `Promise.all`, but you would then need to make both your timeouts into promises too, another option is just keep a counter, increment on each timeout, and then resolve when equal 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `async` function and wait for the two operations end.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
var coreData = {}

var firstMethod = function() {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //First number I want to resolve
    let firstRandomNum = Math.random();
    setTimeout(function() {
      //console.log('First Number; ' + firstRandomNum);
      coreData.firstRandomNumber = firstRandomNum;
      resolve(coreData);
    }, 2 * firstRandomNum);
  });
  return promise;
};

var anotherFirstMethod = function() {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //Second number I want to resolve
    let secondRandomNum = Math.random();
    setTimeout(function() {
      //console.log('Second Number; ' + secondRandomNum);
      coreData.secondRandomNumber = secondRandomNum;
      resolve(coreData);
    }, 2 * secondRandomNum);
  });

  return promise;
};

//Here is where I'd like both *both* numbers to resolve to
var secondMethod = async function(someStuff) {
  await Promise.all([firstMethod(), anotherFirstMethod()])

  console.log('All complete');
  console.log(coreData);
};

secondMethod();
```

See? now your logic is synchronized.

## Resource

- [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

## UPDATE

As suggested by [@Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870228/keith) use the function `Promise.all()`

> With `await Promise.all([firstMethod(), anotherFirstMethod()])` both methods can  run in parallel.

## Approach using function `Promise.all()`.

```js
var coreData = {}

var firstMethod = function() {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //First number I want to resolve
    let firstRandomNum = Math.random();
    setTimeout(function() {
      //console.log('First Number; ' + firstRandomNum);
      coreData.firstRandomNumber = firstRandomNum;
      resolve(coreData);
    }, 2 * firstRandomNum);
  });
  return promise;
};

var anotherFirstMethod = function() {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //Second number I want to resolve
    let secondRandomNum = Math.random();
    setTimeout(function() {
      //console.log('Second Number; ' + secondRandomNum);
      coreData.secondRandomNumber = secondRandomNum;
      resolve(coreData);
    }, 2 * secondRandomNum);
  });

  return promise;
};

//Here is where I'd like both *both* numbers to resolve to
var secondMethod = function() {
  Promise.all([firstMethod(), anotherFirstMethod()]).then(() => {
    console.log('All complete');
    console.log(coreData);
  });  
};

secondMethod();
```

Comment: In the above you have now made `anotherFirstMethod` have to wait until `firstMethod` has finished,..  eg. if they both took 1 second to complete, it will now take 2 seconds for both to complete instead of 1.  but you could do `await Promise.all([firstMethod(), anotherFirstMethod()])`  so that both methods can still run in parallel.